# Object inside a threaded multiprocess is empty

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I have an odd situation here. I have a multiprocess that in turn has a thread. The idea here is to offload the work of appending to a queue to the thread (I'm trying to get my CPU usage up per python process).

Anyways, here's the odd part. I'm appending my results to a deque, and inside the thread attempting to send it through a Queue. However, the thread does not see the results appended to the deque, even though the object id's are the same.

Here is some code/output:

```
class QueueAppender(Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue=None, read_deque=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QueueAppender, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.queue = queue
        self.contents = read_deque

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print 'queue', id(self.contents), len(self.contents)
            if self.contents:
                results = self.contents.popleft()
                if results is None:
                    return
                self.queue.put(results)
            else:
                time.sleep(0.01)

class Worker(Process):
    def __init__(self, queue=None, results=None):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.queue=queue
        self.results = results # a Queue as well
        self.read_deque = deque()
        self.queuethread = QueueAppender(queue=self.results, read_deque=self.read_deque)
        self.queuethread.start()

    def run(self):
        results = self.results
        get_func = self.queue.get
        reads = get_func()
        while reads is not None:
            result_batch = []
            for read in reads:
                    # do some work here
                    result_batch.append(read)
            self.read_deque.append(result_batch)
            print 'worker', id(self.read_deque), len(self.read_deque)
            reads = get_func()
        self.read_deque.append(None)
        self.t.join()
```

The odd part is the output:

```
worker 140413597195744 6
queue 140413597195744 0
queue 140413597195744 0
queue 140413597195744 0
worker 140413597195744 7
queue 140413597195744 0
queue 140413597195744 0
queue 140413597195744 0
```

To me, this says they both are accessing the same memory, but the worker sees items in it, wheras the queue sees 0 items.

Any ideas why this is occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the Thread was being created in the **init**. Moving creation to the run process solved this.